# How to setup path for maven

Tags: linux, maven-2, maven

I am trying to setup a path variable for my maven installation. The system information is like:

```
 [user1@machine1]~% whereis maven
 maven: /etc/maven
 [user1@machine1]~% cd /etc/maven
 [user1@machine1]/etc/maven% ls
 maven2-depmap.xml
```

should I setup path like

```
export MAVEN_HOME=/home/user1/etc/maven/
```

But based on `ls` command, it seems that there does not exist the binary maven file except `maven2-depmap.xml` under `/etc/maven/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command is named `mvn`. I have no idea what `/etc/maven` would be, it seems like some crazed Linux distro person's idea of a joke; it certainly isn't a maven home.

Please download an ordinary tarball of maven from maven.apache.org, and unpack it in `/opt`. You don't have to set `MAVEN_HOME`, just put `/opt/apache-maven-whatever/bin` in your path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is that it seems that maven works just fine on my system. Does that mean that I have to remove the existing maven and re-install it? Thanks.

Comment: No. it means that you should (a) start by typing 'which mvn' instead of 'which maven' and (b) don't bother with MAVEN_HOME at all.

Comment: In order to use mvn with Jenkins, MAVEN_HOME must be defined.

Comment: Why do you think that Jenkins is at issue here?

Answer (score 6):

Here it is, just change path to you downloads...

```
 # set Java, Maven and Hadoop:
 JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java-7-oracle/jdk1.7.0_45"
 export JAVA_HOME
 set PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

MAVEN_HOME="/home/YOUR_NAME/Downloads/apache-maven-3.1.1"
export MAVEN_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin

HADOOP_HOME="/home/YOUR_NAME/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1"
export HADOOP_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

`export M2_HOME=Maven` installed location
`export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}`

Add both the line in `sudo vi /etc/profile.d/maven.sh`